# Определение типа шрифта

Tags: шрифты, php

Загружаю в админке шрифты с клиента (браузера). Мне нужно определить тип шрифта: жирный, обычный, курсив, курсив с жирным.

Как это возможно сделать?
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос решен, правда не простым способом: пришлось писать код самому.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, невозможно, разве что что-нибудь им написать и проверить заполненность.
Впрочем, если условиться, что автор шрифта добросовестный человек, можно ориентироваться по таблице вариаций.

Переменная ['gvar'](http://developer.apple.com/fonts/ttrefman/rm06/Chap6gvar.html) шрифтового файла - то, что нужно. Остается проблема: неизвестно какой из этих вариаций отдаст предпочтение пользователь.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял загружаете вы файлы шрифтов в админке. По поводу начертания (жирный, обычный, курсив, и т.д.) -то это относится к форматированию и определяется соответствующими тегами HTML формата:

```
 <I>курсивом</I>
 <STRONG>сильный</STRONG> ( рекомендуется использовать вместо <B>жирный</B>)
```

Comment: Тут html не присутствует вообще!) 
Я тут уже немного накопал инфы и скажу что вопрос задан ну очень упрощенно.

Эти шрифты будут использоваться при формировании картинок с текстом. А в редакторе текста будут кномпки жирности и курсива. А жирность и курсив зависят от файла используемого шрифта. То есть чтобы реализовать и жирный и курсив и обычный нужно как минимум на данный шрифт четыре файла шрифта. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь!)